# Convert Tick Data to OHLC in Realtime with Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, charts, candlestick-chart

I know how to convert static Tick data to OHLC Candlestick data using resampling with Pandas Module of Python.

**But how can I do this in Realtime (Just like a Websocket sends it)?**

Let's say I am using this while loop code to prepare Tick Data

```
import time, requests

ohlc []
while True:
    r = requests.get('https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHUSDT')
    resp_dict = r.json()
    time.time()
    print({'time' : time.time(), 'price' : resp_dict["price"]})
```

Now, how can I keep resample this data in Realtime with Pandas (**Just like a Websocket keeps sending us this OHLC data every second which makes it possible to plot candlestick data in realtime**)?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

I mean, unless you wanna deploy a data provider business it's all cool to make a standalone autonomous bot.
In realtime you gotta actually aggregate OHLC bars live.

1. Ticks(trades) via WebSocket (or another streaming API); ->
2. Queue to hold dem ticks; ->
3. logic to take em ticks from the queue, send em to an aggregator logic and pop em out of the queue so we won't accidentally process one tick several times; ->
4. Logic to aggregate OHLCV live;
5. Logic to tell when to start constructing a new bar.

FTX exchange & Python, 15 sec chart aggregation. FTX has an ["official" WebSocket Client](https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/tree/master/websocket), I modified it to process all the ticks correctly;

```
def _handle_trades_message(self, message: Dict) -> None:
    self._trades[message['market']].extend(reversed(message['data']))
```

After that, that's what I got:

```
import ftx
import time
import pandas as pd
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from datetime                          import datetime

def process_tick(tick):
    global data
    global flag
    global frontier
    
    if (flag == True) and (tick['time'] >= frontier):
        start_time = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() #"almost"
        time_      = time.time() * 1000 # with higher precision
        op         = tick['price']
        hi         = tick['price']
        lo         = tick['price']
        cl         = tick['price']
        vol        = tick['size' ]
        row        = {'startTime' : start_time, 
                      'time'      : time_     , 
                      'open'      : op        , 
                      'high'      : hi        , 
                      'low'       : lo        , 
                      'close'     : cl        ,
                      'volume'    : vol        }
        data       = data.append(row, True)
        flag = False
        print('Opened')
        print(tick)
    else:
        
        if   (tick['price'] > data['high'].iloc[-1]):
            data['high'].iloc[-1] = tick['price']
        elif (tick['price'] < data['low' ].iloc[-1]):
            data['low' ].iloc[-1] = tick['price']

        data['close' ].iloc[-1]  = tick['price']
        data['volume'].iloc[-1] += tick['size' ]
        print(tick)
     
def on_tick():
    
    while True:

        try:

            try:
                process_tick(trades[-1])
                trades.pop()
            except IndexError:
                pass

            time.sleep(0.001)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            client_ws._reset_data()
            scheduler.remove_job('onClose')
            scheduler.shutdown()
            print('Shutdown')
            break
    
def on_close():
    global flag
    global frontier
    flag     = True
    frontier = pd.Timestamp.utcnow().floor('15S').isoformat() #floor to 15 secs
    print('Closed')

ASSET = 'LTC-PERP'
RES   = '15'

flag      = True
frontier  = pd.Timestamp.utcnow().floor('15S').isoformat() #floor to 15 secs
cols      = ['startTime', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
data      = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
client_ws = ftx.FtxClientWs()
client_ws._subscribe({'channel': 'trades', 'market': ASSET})
trades    = client_ws._trades[ASSET]
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.configure(timezone='utc')
scheduler.add_job(on_close, trigger='cron', second='0, 15, 30, 45', id='onClose')
scheduler.start()    
on_tick()
```

On top of my stuff, just make `on_tick()` run in its own thread, `data` variable will be constantly updated in the background and hold the OHLCV, so you'll be able to use this data within the same program.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option("display.width", None)

flag = True

# Initialize your local time zone
local_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')  # Replace 

# Initialize frontier using a single line
frontier = pd.Timestamp.now(tz=local_timezone).floor('60S').isoformat()


def process_tick(tick):
    global data
    global flag
    global frontier

# Print flag status and frontier value
# print("Flag Status:", flag)
print("Frontier Value:", frontier)
print("tick_time:", tick['time'])

if (flag == True) and (tick['time'] >= frontier):
    start_time = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
    time_ = time.time() * 1000
    op = float(tick['ltp'])
    hi = float(tick['ltp'])
    lo = float(tick['ltp'])
    cl = float(tick['ltp'])
    vol = float(tick['volume'])
    row = {'startTime': start_time,
           'time': time_,
           'open': op,
           'high': hi,
           'low': lo,
           'close': cl,
           'volume': vol}
    data = data.append(row, True)
    flag = False
    print('Opened')
    # print(data)
else:
    if (float(tick['ltp']) > data['high'].iloc[-1]):
        data['high'].iloc[-1] = float(tick['ltp'])
    elif (float(tick['ltp']) < data['low'].iloc[-1]):
        data['low'].iloc[-1] = float(tick['ltp'])

    data['close'].iloc[-1] = float(tick['ltp'])
    data['volume'].iloc[-1] += float(tick['volume'])
    print(data)


def on_tick(ticks):
    for tick in ticks:
       try:
          process_tick(tick)
       except KeyboardInterrupt:
          print('Shutdown')
          break


def on_close():
    global flag
    global frontier
    flag = True
    frontier = pd.Timestamp.now(tz=local_timezone).floor('60S').isoformat()
    print('Closed')


# Initialize Data Storage
cols = ['startTime', 'time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols).astype({'open': float, 'high': float, 
'low': float, 'close': float})

# Kafka consumer configuration
consumer_config = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'my-group60',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'latest'  # Start consuming from the beginning of 
the topic
}

# Create a Kafka consumer instance
consumer = Consumer(consumer_config)

# Subscribe to a Kafka topic for tick data
topic = 'topictrading'  # Replace with the actual Kafka topic name
consumer.subscribe([topic])

# Create a scheduler to run on_close every 60 seconds
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.configure(timezone='Asia/Kolkata')
# scheduler.add_job(on_close, 'interval', seconds=60)
scheduler.add_job(on_close, trigger='cron', second='59', id='onClose')
scheduler.start()



try:
    while True:
    msg = consumer.poll(1.0)
    if msg is None:
        continue
    if msg.error():
        if msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
            continue
        else:
            print(msg.error())
            break
    if msg is None:
        continue
    tick = json.loads(msg.value().decode('utf-8'))
    on_tick([tick])  # Process the received tick data

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    consumer.close()
```

> but m getting this
> C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\tradingprojects\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\tradingprojects\1_min_ohlc-copy.py
> Frontier Value: 2023-09-04T21:52:00+05:30
> tick_time: 2023-09-04 21:22:41
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\tradingprojects\1_min_ohlc-copy.py", line 119, in 
> on_tick([tick])  # Process the received tick data
> File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\tradingprojects\1_min_ohlc-copy.py", line 64, in on_tick
> process_tick(tick)
> File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\tradingprojects\1_min_ohlc-copy.py", line 51, in process_tick
> if (float(tick['ltp']) > data['high'].iloc[-1]):
> File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\tradingprojects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1153, in **getitem**
> return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
> File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\tradingprojects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1714, in _getitem_axis
> self._validate_integer(key, axis)
> File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\tradingprojects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1647, in _validate_integer
> raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34944830)