# Convert realtime tick data to ohlc

Tags: python

I know that there was a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70467422/convert-tick-data-to-ohlc-in-realtime-with-python-pandas) already to ask how to convert tick data to ohlc in realtime in python, but I can not run the example code of the answer.

I recap the example code provided by the auther Rakesh Poddar as follows:

```
import time, requests
while True:
    r = requests.get('https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHUSDT')
    resp_dict = r.json()
    time.time()
    print({'time' : time.time(), 'price' : resp_dict["price"]})
```

In pandas, we can use the function resample to convert static tick data to ohlc. In the case of real time data, how can we convert the realtime tick data to ohlc? In other words, how can we get the ohlc one by one in realtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the overhead, you can just re-instantiate the DataFrame everytime:

```
import time, requests
import pandas as pd

def to_ohlc(ticks: list[dict], tf: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame(ticks)
    df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit="s")
    df["price"] = df["price"].astype(float)
    df = df.set_index("time")
    return pd.DataFrame(df.price.resample(tf).ohlc())

ticks = []
while True:
    r = requests.get('https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHUSDT')
    resp_dict = r.json()
    time.time()
    ticks.append({'time' : time.time(), 'price' : resp_dict["price"]})
    print(to_ohlc(ticks, "1s"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that the output is not the latest updated one. Instead it gives the older data repeatedly. If I want the output dataframe gives only the updated one. May I know how can I do this? Thank you for your help.